# Applying KTable enrichment on data prior to filling row

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I've got sales messages with timestamps and several messages belonging to the same sale share the same ID. But only one contains a field that I want to store in a KTable to enrich follwing messages with the corresponding ID.

**I cannot be sure that the message with the necessary field will always be sent first.**

Is it possible to do a Join including also the messages prior to populating the KTable (let's say timestamps - 5min)?

(What if your data comes in batches with breaks of x min?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if I understand the use case, but it seems you only want to store a message if it contains the corresponding field, but you want to drop the message otherwise. For this case, you could read the data as a `KStream` and apply a filter before you put the records into a table:

```java
KStream input = builder.stream("table-topic");
KTable table = input.filter(/*contains field or is tombstone*/)
                    .toTable();
```

Note, that you might want to ensure that tombstone messages, ie, messages with `value==null` are not filtered out, to preserve delete semantics (seems to be use-case dependent).

Comment: Thank you! I just need to additionally enrich the tombstone messages with the matching  field value I just wrote to the table.

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Can you elaborate? A tombstone is `<key,null>` and I am not sure what you mean by "enrich" for this case? If you change the value from `null` to anything not-`null`, it won't be a tombstone any longer...

Comment: So what I imagine is to save (id -> value of certain field that is only sent once per id) to the KTable but I'd like to enrich all messages with the field according to their id.

Comment: Can you maybe update your question with a concrete example?